# How to align text next to area text?

Tags: css, html

I keep trying to use the vertical-align attribute but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
<label for="title">Title : </label><textarea rows="5" id="title" name="title">      
</textarea>

textarea { vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: your problem caused by your container not the textarea or label try to put full code or link to your work

Answer (score 0):

```
label{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/u44k334r/1/)

Comment: this didn't work, pretty sure im doing something wrong though

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by J.Tural, you problem is probably that the container (probably a div) may too narrow and pushing your textarea down.

Or the container might also have a negative margin or a padding defined.

You should provide more information (a link, a js fiddle, some more html and corresponding css).

Comment: It was from my code. I had written 

    `textarea { display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; } `

I deleted it and used vertical-align:top and it works now. How can I center the textarea now without displacing the text on the right of it?

Comment: Daniel, when you ask a question like this one, could you please provide a snippet of HTML and the corresponding snippet of CSS, please. It is otherwise very difficult to help you. Many thanks

Comment: Im sorry for my ignorance. I am relatively new to this site and dont know all the proper etiquette.

Comment: No problem. Welcome here, if you are developing on a regular basis, you will find this site extremely useful. Just remember to provide enough data about your problem so that readers can understand your questions.
If you have a positioning problem on a webpage, obviously, we need to have some information on your html and your css (and your javascript, as the case may be).

Comment: Ive only been browsing the forums for a week or so and have found a lot of useful tips or information i didnt know. I will try to be more precise with my posts in the future thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to implement the style to the whole form？

`form {vertical-align: top}`

Comment: Some of my code was preventing it from working and removing that fixed it.